# Add Each Generated Code To .txt File - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, save

I Have Button and TextBox. When i click on the button random code generated (working well).
I want each code will be save in the same .txt file. Like this:

my.txt:
RandomCode1
RandomCode2
Random3

I mean when i click on the button the generated code will added to the .txt file (same .txt file for all)

Thank's.

Or (if it's possible)

when i click on the button the program generate random code i need tons like this so maybe i'll click on time and then the program will generate around 100 codes in every single click or the program will not stop until i'll click on another button.

(if it's not easy just help me with the first option.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make 100 codes per click you can do a loop like

```
Dim inc as Integer = 0
Do Until inc = 100
'your code for making code
inc = inc + 1
loop
```

As for text file saving

```
 Dim outfile As StreamWriter
 outfile = File.AppendText("C:\data\codes.txt")
 outfile.Write(TextBox1.text)
 outfile.Flush()
 outfile.Close()
```